# Numbering theorems

Tags: enumerate, theorems, newtheorem

I am looking for a way for counting theorems and propositions by using letters instead of numbers. Looking for on this site, I have found this code:

> \newtheorem{thma}{Theorem}
>
> \newtheorem{propa}{Proposition}
>
> \renewcommand{\thethma}{\Alph{thma}}
>
> \renewcommand{\thepropa}{\Alph{propa}}

However, theorems and propositions are counted separately. Is there a way for a counting like below?

> **Theorem A**
>
> **Proposition B**
>
> **Theorem C**

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: have you tried \renewcommand{\thethm}{\Alph{thm}} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{thma}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{propa}[thma]{Proposition}
\renewcommand{\thethma}{\Alph{thma}}
\renewcommand{\thepropa}{\Alph{propa}}
\begin{document}
\begin{thma}
  AAA
\end{thma}
\begin{propa}
  BBB
\end{propa}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: For some reason unknown to me, I wasn't able to it 30' ago. I did it right now.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a part of any instruduction that mentions how `\newtheorem` works. In this case the `thma` and `propa` envs define their own separate counters as well. But using the proper syntax you can tell `propa` to use the same counter as `thma`

```
\newtheorem{thma}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{propa}[thma]{Proposition}
\renewcommand{\thethma}{\Alph{thma}}
```

as both are not using the same counter, there is no `\thepropa` anymore

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!